# How to switch to <html="rtl"> from a component?

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-translate

I'm using Angular 6, and ngx-translate. The only way to switch to rtl without messing the theme is `<html dir="rtl">` in index.html.

In `component.ts`:

```js
switchLanguage(language: string) {
  this.translate.use(language);
  localStorage.setItem('lang', JSON.stringify(language));
}
```

How do I add `dir="rtl"` to `<html>` if `language === "ar"`, otherwise remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I forgot to mention that changing to rtl from a `div` won't work, I tested that before asking the question, the only way to correctly switch the theme is by adding it to `<html>` and you can test that by trying it on [CoreUI Free Angular 2+ Admin Template](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template) which is what I'm using.

I managed to solve it by

```
  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    if (language !== 'ar' && document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].hasAttribute('dir')) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].removeAttribute('dir');
    } else if (language === 'ar' && !document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].hasAttribute('dir')) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('lang', language);

  }
```

If anyone has a better solution, let me know, I'll upvote and accept yours of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the input form the html tag,
and make a global variable for language, this way you will be able to change it by logic too.

and you can just use binding into your components:

```
<div  [dir]="isRtl"></div>
```

Comment: Upvote for the effort, but that won't work, please read my answer to know why and it's my mistake for not making it clear why i must control the `<html>` tag